# Is there any way to open .map file in QGIS?

Tags: java, qgis, mapsforge

I got a mapsforge/vtm file with extension *.map. How do i open this file in qgis, and can i?

I saw through all the internet, but did not find needed information. Tried to convert this file by any means. Was looking for the qgis module, that could help me. Nothing worked.